# Missing validation message using DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am working on a c# project using mvc. I have a create form and in it i have a dropdown. The dropdown field is a required field (in my model). But when i don't choose a value from the dropdown and click the "Create" button, i have no validation message (even though i have one in my model class). Here is my model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
public int MappingType { get; set; }
```

Here is my view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.id, new SelectList(ViewBag.mappingTypes, "Value", "Text"), "Choose")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MappingType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

I don't know where i make a mistake..

Comment: The property you have shown is named `MappingType` but the dropdownlist you are generatibg is for a property named `id`! (and why are you creating a new `SelectList` from `ViewBag.mappingTypes` when its already a `SelectList`?

Comment: Do you mean that i should add "id" property in my model and to make it required and then to change the view like this:@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.id, new SelectList(ViewBag.mappingTypes, "Value", "Text"), "Изберете")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

Comment: Or `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MappingType, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.mappingTypes, "Choose")` since that seems to be what you want to bind to.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just tried your suggestion (@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MappingType, ....)) and the validation message appeared!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are generating dropdownlist for another property on model. I.e. You are creating dropdownlist for `id` while validation message is for `MappingType`. In order to make it work both control (in your case dropdownlist) and validation message should be for same property. So change following line

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.id, new SelectList(ViewBag.mappingTypes, "Value", "Text"), "Choose")
```

to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MappingType, new SelectList(ViewBag.mappingTypes, "Value", "Text"), "Choose")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use viewdata to bind dropdown like below.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.id,(SelectList)ViewData["mappingTypes"],"Choose")
```

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MappingType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })